# Find k highest values in each column and compute mean in R

Tags: r, statistics

I am trying to calculate the average of each column in a dataframe using the top k values. I have a solution, however, it is slow and hamfisted. Here is what I came up with:

```
predictMat <- matrix(0,nrow = length(colnames(DT)),ncol = 1)
k <- 100

itemSummary <- for(i in colnames(DT)) {
  u <- data.frame(DT[,i , drop = F])
  sortU1 <- data.frame(u[order(u[,i], decreasing = T),, drop = F])
  u1Neighbors <- data.matrix(sortU1[1:k,, drop = F])
  predictMat[i] <- mean(u1Neighbors, na.rm = T)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this in one line using the `apply` function:

```
# Sample data frame
set.seed(144)
DT <- matrix(rnorm(1000), nrow=100)
k <- 10

# Compute average of 10 largest values in each column
apply(DT, 2, function(x) mean(tail(sort(x), k)))
# [1] 1.721765 1.658917 1.630231 1.558280 1.606363 1.526322 1.810814 1.678135
# [9] 1.541305 1.621984
```

Answer (score 1):

could do this with back-to-back apply functions

```
set.seed(100)
x <- as.data.frame ( matrix(runif(5000,0,10), nrow=1000,ncol=5) )

x1<-  apply(x,2,sort,decreasing=T)
apply(x1[1:100,],2,mean) 


      V1       V2       V3       V4       V5 
9.548000 9.572912 9.422325 9.547370 9.462894
```

edit: looks like I was a few seconds behind in my answer!

Comment: Because you're storing a second copy of your data in `x1`, this could be pretty inefficient if you have a dataset with many rows.